# Estimate the similarity of a curve to a gaussian distribution (in Python)

Tags: python, curve-fitting, gaussian

I want to quantify the similarity of a curve of measurement values to a gaussian distribution with Python.

Two arrays of values are given:

`H=(0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,50,70)` is the height in meters

`C(H)=(0,1,1,2,4,6,7,5,3,1,0)` is the measured quantity (e.g. concentration)

Is there a way in Python to

a) fit a gaussian curve to the values of `C(H)`?

b) get some kind of coefficient of similarity that describes how similar the curve is to a gaussian curve?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This seems like more of a math question than a programming question. Can you be precise about what it means for some curve to be "similar to" another? Can you write a mathematical formula that gives you an appropriate metric?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be a math question, not a programming question.

Comment: I would also prefer if the question were spelled out, but at least it's concrete enough to allow for fairly precise answers, and you could argue that the "Is there a way in Python" part of it turns it into a programming question. You could also argue that this puts it into the "framework recommendation" off-topic category.

Comment: I am sorry for not being precise enough. This question came up from some scientific work of mine. I didn't had a concrete formula for a measure of similarity, but the way of calculating RMSE and R squared value seem that James Philips presented seem to be reasonable.
Thank you for not closing the thread. I asked the same already in a mathematic forum but nobody there could help me up to now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you specifically ask for Python code, here is a graphical Python curve fitter using your data and fitting to a Gaussian peak equation. The RMSE and R-squared values should be a useful measure of similarity, as together they describe the quality of a Gaussian fit for the data.

[image: plot]

```
import numpy, scipy, matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

H=(0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,50,70) 
C=(0,1,1,2,4,6,7,5,3,1,0)

xData = numpy.array(H, dtype=float)
yData = numpy.array(C, dtype=float)


def func(x, a, b, c): # Gaussian peak
    return  a * numpy.exp(-0.5 * numpy.power((x-b) / c, 2.0))


# estimate initial parameters from the data
a_est = max(C)
b_est = (max(H) + min(H)) / 2
c_est = max(C)
initialParameters = numpy.array([a_est, b_est, c_est], dtype=float)

# curve fit the test data
fittedParameters, pcov = curve_fit(func, xData, yData, initialParameters)

modelPredictions = func(xData, *fittedParameters) 

absError = modelPredictions - yData

SE = numpy.square(absError) # squared errors
MSE = numpy.mean(SE) # mean squared errors
RMSE = numpy.sqrt(MSE) # Root Mean Squared Error, RMSE
Rsquared = 1.0 - (numpy.var(absError) / numpy.var(yData))

print('Parameters:', fittedParameters)
print('RMSE:', RMSE)
print('R-squared:', Rsquared)

print()


##########################################################
# graphics output section
def ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)
    axes = f.add_subplot(111)

    # first the raw data as a scatter plot
    axes.plot(xData, yData,  'D')

    # create data for the fitted equation plot
    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(xData), max(xData))
    yModel = func(xModel, *fittedParameters)

    # now the model as a line plot
    axes.plot(xModel, yModel)

    axes.set_xlabel('X Data') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data') # Y axis data label

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot

graphWidth = 800
graphHeight = 600
ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight)
```

Comment: From a statistical/probability theoretical point of view, it's rather unclear what this process achieves, and what estimators you are calculating (certainly they're not MLEs).

Comment: @fuglede this process achieves curve fitting of the posted data to a Gaussian peak equation, and the single estimator is the lowest sum of squared error.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try this procedure with my real data and discuss the results with my supervisor.

Comment: The "all 0" fit was due to my using the default initial parameter estimates of all 1.0, I have edited the code to make initial parameter estimates based on the data. Please try the updated source code.

Comment: Hey. I already deleted the question, because I found out that this is caused by the initial parameters. I simply set the parameter b = 2 to avoid "all 0" fit, but your solution is probably even better. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, what you're asking is whether it is possible to use Python to estimate the parameters of a normal population describing your data. There are infinitely many estimators to choose from, but if what you're looking for are the maximum likelihood estimates, those are nothing but the sample mean and sample standard deviations, which you can easily find with vanilla Python or something like NumPy:

```
In [22]: H = [0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,50,70]

In [23]: C = [0,1,1,2,4,6,7,5,3,1,0]

In [24]: a = np.repeat(H, C)

In [25]: a
Out[25]:
array([ 5, 10, 15, 15, 20, 20, 20, 20, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 30, 30, 30,
       30, 30, 30, 30, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 40, 40, 40, 50])

In [26]: a.mean(), a.std()
Out[26]: (27.666666666666668, 9.46337971105226)
```

Parameter estimation for many common distributions are available in SciPy, and could also be used here:

```
In [27]: scipy.stats.norm.fit(a)
Out[27]: (27.666666666666668, 9.46337971105226)
```

The second question is rather vague but is specific enough that the answer lies in determining the "[goodness of fit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodness_of_fit)" of the normal model, or, somewhat more generally, finding an appropriate "[normality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normality_test)" for your data. The Wikipedia articles list statistical tests that apply once you know what you want to check, but without further assumptions, there's no silver bullet. Chances are that a qualitative tool like a [Q–Q plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q%E2%80%93Q_plot) might tell you want you want to know; with your given sample it's a bit hard to tell, but I assume your actual data is different from what you provided here.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.stats as st
st.probplot(a, dist=st.norm, plot=plt)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, my actual data is different to this, but I will try to calculate Q-Q plots with the way you showed me to get a qualitative idea. It appears to be very promising.